# iOS:Selection and saving data or print the data when row is selected in table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Iam using the did select method to select the data .so data in a particular row is selecting and  aim getting the check mark also now my problem is when the check mark is on state the data should be printed in console and if its off the data should be removed from the array. my code is  as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  NSLog(@"array is %@",array);
  static NSString *CustomCellID = @"cell";
  contactcellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellID];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell=[[contactcellTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CustomCellID];
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"contactcellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell =[nib objectAtIndex:0];
  }
  cell.Firstnamelbl.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"first_name"];
  cell.Lastnamelbl.text=[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"last_name"];
  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [array removeAllObjects];
  contactcellTableViewCell *cell = (contactcellTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  static NSString *CustomCellID = @"cell";
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell=[[contactcellTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CustomCellID];
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"contactcellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell =[nib objectAtIndex:0];
  }
  if (cell.m_checkImageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected.png"])
     cell.m_checkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Unselected.png"];

  else
     cell.m_checkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected.png"];
}
```

I had two labels in cell so that when the particular row is selected the data should be print on the console

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer please find below

```
if (cell.m_checkImageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected.png"])

{
    cell.m_checkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Unselected.png"];


}
else
{
    cell.m_checkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected.png"];

   NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
}
}
```

now we will see the data when row is selected